# Login error on Windows form. (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#

I am currently facing the issue with login. I can register but I can't login with the same username and password. I don't know what has happened to the login thing. I use debugger and tried but it didn't help for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

My Login functionality is below.

```
   private void loginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (username.Text.Length == 0 || password.Text.Length == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter username and password", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        else
        {
            var userValue = User.userList.Where(p => p.userName == username.Text && p.password == password.Text).ToList();
            if (userValue.Count == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username and password", "Stop", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            else
            {

                User.selectedUsers = new List<Users>();
                User.selectedUsers.Add(new Users
                {

                    userName = Value[0].userName,
                    password = Value[1].password
                });
                TextEditor text = new TextEditor();
                text.ShowDialog();

            }
        }
    }
```

The **userList** has the number of users with their **username**, **password**, **first name**, **lastname** and **dob**. **selectedUsers** has a list of users.

Hope you get it. If you want something else then please ping me, I am ready to provide. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the text of the error? Or is it just that your code doesn't work as you wish?

Comment: @MaxB it says Invalid username and password even though I entered the right username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you better not save the password as a plain text, it's a no no... 
The procedure, as far as I know, is to 'hash' the password using some extended library, and save the hash code you get to db. Later when user tries to log in, you hash the password he used again and check whether it's the same hash code you have in your DB.

Back to business, your life really would be much easier if you just debugged the code and check what are the values for "username.Text" and "password.Text" at the point where you get an error message. Also look into the "User.userList" with your eyes and see if it really has the name and password you're looking for.

Here's a little screenshot of how it's supposed to be checked, you just hover over the stuff with your mouse and it shows you its contents.
[image: Debug process]

I'm sorry if you already know all this stuff and it's obvious for you, but really, your only problem here is a bad debugging imo.

Comment: yep got it and we're not allowed to use the other library. Thanks.